# Not able to add option in Sub-Menu under page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am using the "Enhanced media library plugin",
this plugin has four submenus, []

1)media

2)media-library

3)media-taxonomies

4)mime-types

I am trying to add a few options under the media-library page, but am not able to do it, where if I use the same code to add an option under "MEDIA(1)" it's working but not working on page 2,3,4.

I found this code on enternet

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_general_section');  

function my_general_section() {  
add_settings_section(  
    'media', // Section ID 
    'My Options Title', // Section Title
    'my_section_options_callback', // Callback
    'media' // What Page?  This makes the section show up on the General Settings Page
);

add_settings_field( // Option 1
    'option_1', // Option ID
    'Option 1', // Label
    'my_textbox_callback', // !important - This is where the args go!
    'media', // Page it will be displayed (General Settings)
    'media', // Name of our section
    array( // The $args
        'option_1' // Should match Option ID
    )  
); 

add_settings_field( // Option 2
    'option_2', // Option ID
    'Option 2', // Label
    'my_textbox_callback', // !important - This is where the args go!
    'media', // Page it will be displayed
    'media', // Name of our section (General Settings)
    array( // The $args
        'option_2' // Should match Option ID
    )  
); 

register_setting('media','option_1', 'esc_attr');
register_setting('media','option_2', 'esc_attr');
}
```

Am also sharing a link to the plugin code file which handles the pages and sub-menu,
[Plugin Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsFWQ8Q7RPF-41Joe9d6Oq5qGyvpd5nJ/view?usp=sharing)

kindly help me out with this, in case I missed something please let me know.

Comment: Hi Rajneesh - welcome to WPSE. This site focuses on custom code and Core, not third-party plugins. You're likely to receive more help if you reach out directly to the plugin author.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "Enhanced media library" plugin doesn't follow the Settings API,
just because of this you can't enhance the plugin options using Settings API.
But you can use Jquery to add the option to any section of EMB or you can create your own custom page or can add options in "WP MEDIA SECTION" using settings API.

I am sharing the Jquery code in case you still want to add options inside EMB pages.

```
add_action('admin_head','custom_aenhaced_media_manager_js'); 
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_aenhaced_media_manager_js' ) ) {
function custom_aenhaced_media_manager_description_handler_js()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow == 'options-general.php' && ($_GET['page']=="media-library")){
        $wpuxss_eml_lib_options = get_option( 'wpuxss_eml_lib_options', array() );
      
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        let description_status="<?php echo $wpuxss_eml_lib_options['hide_the_media'];?>";
        var html='<tr><th scope="row">Image Description</th>';
        html+='<td><fieldset>';
        html+='<legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Include children</span></legend>';
        html+='<legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Include children</span></legend>';
        html+=' <label><input name="wpuxss_eml_lib_options[hide_the_media]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input name="wpuxss_eml_lib_options[hide_the_media]" type="checkbox" value="1" ';
        if(description_status=="1")
        {
            html+=checked="checked";
        }
        html+=' /> Show description under caption on single images in articles</label>';
        html+='  </fieldset>  </td>';
        html+='</tr>';
        jQuery('#wpuxss-eml-form-taxonomies table:first > tbody > tr:last').after(html);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}}}
```

In case of any issues let me know.
Make sure to change wpuxss_eml_lib_options[hide_the_media] according to your section and tabs.